# inputting values into an array as UIbutton is being clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I'm building a dice game. I have 5 dices. I roll them all to get a random value for all 5 dices. I add each dice, and I get a 8 "sumTotal" printed out into a label.

1. I want to know how can I store each values "sumTotal" into an array each time the user clicks a button.
2. I want to know how once I get to print out the number 8 total. How can I remove it, and add the next value to the beginning of the label.

Thank you

```
- (IBAction)rollDice:(id)sender {
    self.die1Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    self.die2Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    self.die3Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    self.die4Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    self.die5Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;

    [self.dieOne setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die1Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.dieTwo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die2Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.dieThree setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die3Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.dieFour setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die4Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.dieFive setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die5Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.sumTotal = self.die1Value + self.die2Value + self.die3Value + self.die4Value + self.die5Value;

    if (self.numberOfLines <= 8) {
      //  if (self.numberOfLines <= 8) {
        NSString *i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nTotal is: %d", self.sumTotal];
        self.totalLabelIt.text = [self.totalLabelIt.text stringByAppendingString:i];

        if (self.numberOfLines > 8) {
            //  if (self.numberOfLines <= 8) {
            NSString *i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nTotal issss: %d", self.sumTotal];
            self.totalLabelIt.text = [self.totalLabelIt.text stringByAppendingString:i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted and a specific issue that you are having?

Comment: Hi Paul, I just added the Method I have so far for this functionality. I get to print out the Total is: XXXX in separate lines, but only up to 8 lines. On the 9th and after I would like to remove one from the bottom, and add another on top. Is it possible to save score in an array everytime a user clicks the roll button? Thank you

Comment: You should investigate an array to store your totals and it is probably simpler to use a table view to display your results

Comment: If its not to much trouble can you give me a more in depth view on how I can store value in the array everytime the user clicks the roll button, and how can I manipulated on the fly? Thanks

Comment: I'm searching an I can't find a clear example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your totals in an array.  The following code stores the totals and after 8 totals, starts again at the beginning of the array.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray totals;
@property NSInteger arrayPointer;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.totals=[NSMutableArray new];
     self.arrayPointer=0;
}


- (IBAction)rollDice:(id)sender {

self.die1Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
self.die2Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
self.die3Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
self.die4Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
self.die5Value = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;

[self.dieOne setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die1Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.dieTwo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die2Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.dieThree setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die3Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.dieFour setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die4Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.dieFive setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.die5Value ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSInteger sumTotal = self.die1Value + self.die2Value + self.die3Value + self.die4Value + self.die5Value;

[self addTotalToArray:sumTotal];


if (self.numberOfLines <= 8) {
  //  if (self.numberOfLines <= 8) {
    NSString *i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nTotal is: %d", self.sumTotal];
    self.totalLabelIt.text = [self.totalLabelIt.text stringByAppendingString:i];

    if (self.numberOfLines > 8) {
        //  if (self.numberOfLines <= 8) {
        NSString *i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nTotal issss: %d", self.sumTotal];
        self.totalLabelIt.text = [self.totalLabelIt.text stringByAppendingString:i];

    }

}

-(void) addTotalToArray:(NSInteger) total {
    NSNumber totalNum=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:total];
    if (self.arrayPointer > self.totals.count-1) {
        [self.totals addObject:totalNum];
    } else {
        self.totals[self.arrayPointer]=totalNum;
    }

    if (++self.arrayPointer == 8) { 
        self.arrayPointer=0;
    }
}
```

As I said in my comment, I would suggest that you use the array to drive a `UITableView` rather than trying to manipulate a label

Comment: Ok great, thank you. I'm going to start playing with UITableView. The bootcamp I'm attending told us to use a Label I didn't get it either. If I ever have questions about objective-c/xcode, how can I ask you directly? I seen your profile you seem very knowledgeable.

Comment: It is better to ask questions to everyone through the site.  I may not be around.